# Possible error in Ahlfors section 3.3.1

Tags: complex-analysis

In Ahlfors, exercise 1 of section 3.2 of chapter 3 (section 3 is on Möbius transformations) states:

> ''Prove that the most general transformation which leaves the origin fixed and preserves distances is either a rotation or a rotation followed by a reflection in the real axis.''

Is this a mistake?

I believe the statement should be:

> Prove that the most general transformation which leaves the origin fixed and preserves distances is a rotation.

For one, in a previous exercise we prove that $z \mapsto \bar{z}$ (i.e. reflection in the real axis) is not a Möbius transformation ($0 \mapsto 0$ implies $S(z) = \frac{az}{cz + d}$, $\infty \mapsto \infty$ implies $S(z) = \frac{a}{d} z$, and $1 \mapsto 1$ implies $S(z) = z$).  Hence, if $S(z)$ were a rotation followed by a reflection in the real axis, then by precomposing with a rotation we would have that reflection in the real axis is a Möbius transformation, since being a Möbius transformation is preserved under composition.

Moreover, here is a direct proof that it must be a rotation.  Since $0 \mapsto 0$ we have $S(z) = \frac{az}{cz + d}$.  Since distance is preserved, $\frac{|a||z|}{|cz + d|} = |z|$ for all $z$, hence $|cz + d|$ is a constant, hence $c = 0$ and $|a| = |d|$.  We conclude $S(z) = e^{i\theta} z$, as desired.

Does my work check out?  Many thanks.

Note:  It is a good point to be made that this is of course true if we're just talking about linear transformations of $\mathbf{R}^2$.  Given that Ahlfors uses the word "linear transformation" to mean Möbius transformation, I admit this is a possible source of confusion.

Comment: Transformation of what? This question needs more context.

Comment: See the note I added at the end of the post.

Comment: But what does "most general transformation" mean in this context? You are still making an assumption that makes Ahlfors wrong, so why make that assumption? And you should put more context at the beginning of your question - it helps people help you.

Comment: I am quoting Ahlfors.

Comment: You are quoting Ahlfors out of any context, so that anybody who doesn't have the book in front of them can't help you. So you are minimizing the number of people to help you *and* you are wasting the time of people who might be able to help you but you are too busy to give them any more context. Help people help you.

Comment: Part of my confusion is indeed what Ahlfors means by "most general transformation".  The reason I think the statement is an error is because in the surrounding context, the word transformation or linear transformation is referring to a Möbius transformation.

Comment: I tried to give context by stating what section 3 is about, and then in response to your suggestion I tried to give more context by saying what Ahlfors means by "transformation" or "linear transformation" in that section.  It appears you do not think this is sufficient, and I do not know what sufficient would be in this instance.

Comment: So, you know there is a perfectly good reading of this problem that makes it true. And it is false if you read it this way. Why are you reading it the false way? The only functions on the plane that fix the origin and preserve distances are the ones desribed. Those are "general transformations." You don't need linear - the happen to all be linear (on the plane.)

Comment: I think that the point Thomas is trying to make is the following: why would any one use "most general transformation" to mean "Mobius transformation" when they can simply say "Mobius transformation" ?

Comment: @N.S.  My answer to that would be that Ahlfors already uses the word linear transformation to mean Möbius transformation, which I believe is not conventional in modern usage; so I really had no idea what he meant.  You both make excellent points.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that the confusion comes from the word transformation.

The statement is (still) true if by "most general transformation" is understood "function", you interpreted this as a Mobius transformation.

So try to prove is this way: If $f : \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ is any function which keeps the origin fixed and preserves the distances, then $f$ is either.....

Comment: And just to be super clear, by "function which keeps the origin fixed and preserves distances" we mean an *isometry* $\mathbf{R}^2 \to \mathbf{R}^2$ fixing the origin, which is indeed an orthogonal transformation.